# Excel formula regarding designating cells with the letter "x" and green colour from 5 numbers chosen out of a set consisting of 42 i a particular way

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

In general I've got a set of 42 number ranging from 1 do 42 in normal order.

Now I pick 5 numbers out of those 42. They are presented in cells from AS to AW. Now I want every nubmer out of those 5 to be represented as an x and that previous x creates 5 xs below it and 2 xs below those as shown in the screenshot. I have been doing this by hand and it takes a lot of time, so I am wondering if this can be automated, so that when I add the next 5 numbers all the xs will just appear 2 rows under.

Additionally I need some xs turning green when a nubmer was selected that has been previously been cover by an x, and also it would be nice when the total number of the green xs would be shown in AQ cell.

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: You can come a long way with some conditional formatting :)

Comment: I am sorry, but this is way to difficult for me. I mean I do not know how to use this tool and after watching a vid about how to, I probably would need a custom one. I know that this is apparently easy, but I am blonde ;) seriously :

Comment: I think you'd need to do this in VBA as it seems it would be really complicated to do using conditional formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get your pattern, put this in A2, copy over and down:

```
=IF(OR(COUNTIF($AS2:$AW2,A$1),IF(ROW()>2,SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDEX($AS:$AW,ROW()-1,0),MOD(COLUMN()-1+{-2,-1,0,1,2},42)+1))>0,FALSE),IF(ROW()>2,SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDEX($AS:$AW,ROW()-2,0),MOD(COLUMN()-1+{-1,1},42)+1))>0,FALSE)),"X","")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank very much from the bottom of my heart Sir :)